# R Connect to Database WITHOUT Java?

Tags: r

I use the RJDBC package to connect to Amazon Redshift and it works ok.  But very often I get a Java Heapsize error and it's really frustrating and not consistent.  Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't.  My problem is that my computer can ONLY use 32bit Java, which also forces me to use 32bit R, which means I can't use all my RAM.

Is there a package that can do this WITHOUT Java?

Comment: Yes but they use rJava as dependencies

Comment: `odbc` [does not use `rJava`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) (neither does [`RODBC`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html)), where do you see that? And none of the AWS-provided instructions reference java, jdk, or jre ([win](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-windows.html), [linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-linux.html), [macos](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-mac.html)).

Comment: I may have misread!  I'll give RODBC a try.